# Dividing numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, concatenation

Hi I am trying to divide a numpy array in 2 pieces and this over a loop such as:

```
main_array.shape = (50, 400, 400, 3)
for i = 0:
 sub_array_1 would be equal to (0:10, 400, 400, 3)
 sub_array_2 would be equal to (10:50, 400, 400, 3)
for i = 1:
 sub_array_1 would be equal to (10:20, 400, 400, 3)
 sub_array_2 would be equal to (20:50, 400, 400, 3)

etc...
```

how to do that ?

I use the following piece of code but I obtain very weird results:

```
i = 0
for k in range(1, k_fold+1):
        sub_array_1 = main_array[np.uint8(i):np.uint8(i+len(main_array)//5)]


        temp_0 = main_array[0:np.uint8(i)]
        temp_1 = main_array[np.uint8(i+len(main_array)//5):]
        sub_array_2 = np.concatenate((temp_0, temp_1), axis=0)
```

Using this I indeed obtain 2 arrays but with weird final shape.

Do I do something wrong here (I guess so) ?

Comment: There's no advantage to casting a scalar integer to `uint8` when indexing.

Comment: You want to collect values in a list, with `alist=[]` and `alist.append(new_array)`.  `np.concatenate` in a loop is slow, and hard to initialize correctly.  Also be careful where you initialize the list - it should be done outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
main_array = np.random.rand(50, 400, 400, 3)
k_fold = 5
step = main_array.shape[0] / k_fold
for i in range(0,k_fold - 1):
    sub_array_1 = main_array[int(step * i):int(step * (i + 1))]
    sub_array_2 = main_array[int(step * (i + 1)):]
    print("sub_array_1: {} -> {}".format(int(step * i),int(step * (i + 1))))
    print(sub_array_1.shape, sub_array_2.shape)
    print()
```

Output:

```
sub_array_1: 0 -> 10
(10, 400, 400, 3) (40, 400, 400, 3)

sub_array_1: 10 -> 20
(10, 400, 400, 3) (30, 400, 400, 3)

sub_array_1: 20 -> 30
(10, 400, 400, 3) (20, 400, 400, 3)

sub_array_1: 30 -> 40
(10, 400, 400, 3) (10, 400, 400, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ExplodingGayFish. I understand however, if sub_array_1 has to be (10,400,400,3) all along, the sub_array_2 should always be (40,400,400,3) but with different part of the main array in it